# recommended way to floor time_point to a given duration

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have a user-provided duration

```
const int period_seconds = cfg.period_seconds;
```

I would like to `floor` a `time_point` to the granularity of that `duration`.

I see that there is a `std::chrono::floor` function for [`time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/floor) and [`duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/floor), but it's not immediately obvious how to use them to do what I'm looking for.

I have the following toy example which works:

```
const auto seconds = std::chrono::seconds{period_seconds};
const auto period = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(seconds);
const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
const auto floored = now - (now.time_since_epoch() % period);
```

The net effect of the above code, for a duration of 10 seconds would be the following:

> ```
> now:     2022-04-19 15:06:26.781772408
> floored: 2022-04-19 15:06:20.000000000    # so "floors" the 25.78 seconds to 20 seconds
> ```

I can't help but feel that working in terms of the `time_since_epoch` and a modulus operator isn't the "right" way of getting the result I'm looking for...

Is there a "better" / recommended way to floor a time_point to some user-provided duration?

Comment: You can try dividing by the period and then multiplying by it again.

Comment: You want to floor to it to seconds or any static number or a some runtime given number? If that's the former then why not just cast into `duration` with that static period?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your solution looks pretty good to me.  However it can be slightly simplified.  There's no need to form the nanoseconds-precision `period`.  You can operate directly with `seconds`:

```
const auto floored = now - (now.time_since_epoch() % seconds);
```